# Is it possible to create a trigger on a table synonym in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

The title says (asks) it all. Is it possible to create a trigger on a table synonym in SQL Server (2005 or higher)?

Comment: What would you hope to accomplish with creating a trigger against a synonym? Random what-if question or is there a business problem you hoped to solve with it?

Comment: @billinkc: Random? Not at all. I have to test an application that creates several triggers on several tables and I made the very naive assumption that if it was possible, I could remove them before each test run by simply dropping the sysonyms (thus dropping the triggers on them as well) without affecting the original triggers on original tables. Now that I know it's not possible, I'll stop being lazy and create a proper removal script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. I assume you tried this, but you will get this error:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 6, Procedure EasyToTest, Line 1
>   
> The object 'dbo.ShowSomeEffort' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

You also can't create a constraint on a synonym, reference a synonym in a foreign key constraint, etc. Most metadata operations must apply to the base table, not the synonym. The synonym is essentially used as a "syntactic sugar" pointer to assist in DML/CRUD, not DDL.

Comment: No, I haven't. By the time I had the chance to try I already got the answer it was not possible, thank you very much.